# How to map F1 to Ctrl+P in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm using the following command:

```
:imap <F1> ^P
```

to map <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in the insert mode.

But it does not work.

Comment: What you wrote is correct. Try `:verbose imap <F1>` to see if it's not mapped elsewere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If that `^P` is two characters, `^` and `P`, it's wrong. It has to be a single character (0x10), entered via `CTRL-V CTRL-P` (or `CTRL-Q CTRL-P` on many Windows versions of Vim, due to the remapping in `mswin.vim`).

Better completely avoid these issues by using the special notation `<C-P>`. Cp. `:help keycodes`

Oh, and when remapping built-in functionality, it's recommended to use `noremap`:

```
:inoremap <F1> <C-P>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine in vim. But when i use the screen, it does not worked rightly. When it input F1, the char "P" is inputed. how can i set in my screenrc? Thanks~

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
:imap <F1> <c-p>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i only choose one answer. so i just up it.